# Ghost hosted at Google Cloud Run tries to connect to Cloud SQL MySQL and gots timeout reading communication packets

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-run, ghost-blog

- I deploy a docker container with Ghost inside, to the Google Cloud Run.
- The Cloud Run service has a service account with Cloud SQL Client role.
- I've added the SQL instance into the connections of the Cloud Run Service.
- The Ghost's configuration file is the below property

```js
  "database": {
    "client": "mysql",
    "connection": {
      "socketPath": "/cloudsql/xxxxxxx",
      "user": "xxxxxxx",
      "password": "xxxxxxx",
      "database": "ghost1"
    }
  },
```

- I have an Google Cloud SQL - MySQL instance up and running. I can connect to it through Public IP and using the same credentials.

After I deploy the container, I am getting a "We'll be right back" page on the Ghost.
When I look into the logs on each side, I see some errors which I do not understand the root cause.

**Examples of the logs at Google Cloud SQL:**

2021-11-14T06:40:37.183921Z 6971 [Warning] User 'mysql.session'@'localhost' was assigned access 0x8000 but was allowed to have only 0x0.

2021-11-14T06:49:09.008652Z 7002 [Note] Aborted connection 7002 to db: 'ghost1' user: 'xxxxxxx' host: 'cloudsqlproxy~107.178.207.100' (Got an error reading communication packets)

2021-11-14T06:50:29.721121Z 7471 [Note] Got timeout reading communication packets

**Examples of the logs at Google Cloud Run**

DatabaseError: Knex: Timeout acquiring a connection. The pool is probably full. Are you missing a .transacting(trx) call? at DatabaseError.KnexMigrateError

I have tried a lot of combinations like using VPC connector and Private IP but I keep getting the same network timeout errors all the time. I suspect that the Ghost mysql adaptor library (knex) is doing something wrong but I am not sure whether that is true and if there is something I can do about it.

Thanks for your help

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/error-messages

Comment: I've already checked this page but was not helpful to me. I don't understand what I am supposed to change

Comment: @MustafaEkim According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40435315/knex-timeout-acquiring-a-connection-the-pool-is-probably-full-are-you-missing), updating your knex version might solve your issue. Also, make sure you are closing your SQL connections when needed as stated [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/manage-connections).

Comment: I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60938880/12512650) similar question which explains how to connect. Please note that the same user made a more in depth explanation [here](https://parondeau.com/blog/self-hosting-ghost-gcp).

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, we have [an example app](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/blob/main/cloud-sql/mysql/mysql/server.js#L92-L100) that connects over Unix sockets.

As long as you're connecting to public IP, you won't need a Serverless VPC Access connector or a Private IP.

Also, you might double check that your socket path is correct. It should look like this: `/cloudsql/project-name:region:instance-name`.

There's a similar question here that might help:

[How do I run Ghost with MySQL on GCP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60013643/how-do-i-run-ghost-with-mysql-on-gcp/60938880#60938880)

Comment: Hi, thanks but according to the Google documentation, socketPath is correct name for the property: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-run

Comment: Oh sorry. I misread and thought you were using Postgres. Let me take another look.

Comment: Updated my answer. Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately the socketPath property's value seems to be correct. I use public IP. I tried to use the Private IP as well. I tried to use with and without connector. I always get the same kind of errors like: [Got an error reading communication packets, User 'mysql.session'@'localhost' was assigned access 0x8000 but was allowed to have only 0x0.]

Comment: Hi @MustafaEkim, did you resolve it? Im getting same errors.

Comment: Unfortunately I could not resolve the issue. I tried many approaches and finally gave up. I doubt that one of the underlying packages that the mysql library uses for establishing a connection with google cloud mysql instance is not supported

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you allow SSL connections only and create a new certificate chain for your instance.

[image: SSL Toggle]

```
       "ssl": {
            "cert": "<database_cert>",
            "ca": "<database_ca>",
            "key": "<database_key>"
       }
```

[example here](https://github.com/behoyh/ghost/blob/master/data/config.production.json)

Answer (score 0):

Activating `SSL connections only` and adding the certificate chain did not work for me.

I am using the unix `socketPath` to connect from Ghost to a CloudSQL database like mentioned above: `/cloudsql/project-name:region:instance-name`.

When running Ghost version 5.x.x the db connection stopped working after some random time. The Cloud Run logs showed:
`Error: connect ETIMEDOUT`
and
`Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.`

I tested my configuration by running Ghost on localhost, using the cloudsql-proxy for authentication and it worked without problems.

I finally got it working on Cloud Run by patching the `node_modules/knex/lib/client.js`. Re-initialise the connection pool and try to reconnect to the database in case the pool has been destroyed.

The approach is also explained here in more detail: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69191743/2546954